# Dynamic Accordion in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on the dynamic accordion. I have implemented and tested, everything is working fine. and decided to move code into my project, however it is slightly different. When you take a look at the accordion header arrow (on the left side), in the jsfiddle it is centered, but in the product, it is not centered. I wonder how to fix the issue.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/47/)

Here is the jsfiddle prototype
[image]

In the product installing jquery:

product code:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height:98%">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>

        .table-holder {
    width:100%;
}
.table-holder table {
    margin:0 auto;
}

#accordion li > text{
    display:inline-block; 
    text-align : center;

}
#accordion .formationName {
    width:200px; 
    text-align : center;
}

#accordion .bitSize {
    width:200px; 
    text-align : center;
}

#accordion .bitType {
    width:100px; 
    text-align : center;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

#accordion li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 0 0 20px;  
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 20px;
}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:12px;
}
.ui-accordion ul {
    margin: 0;
}
#refresh, #build{
    float:right

}

#build
{
     margin-left:5px;
}


.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon{
position: absolute !important;
top: 50% !important;
}
 </style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<div class="accordion-expand-holder">
    <button type="button" id="build">Build</button>
    <button type="button" id="refresh">Refresh</button>
    <button type="button" class="open">Expand all</button>
    <button type="button" class="close">Collapse all</button>
    <div id="accordion">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is snapsot of the product
[image]

Comment: Maybe if you provide us the link of that website we will be able to help you...on fiddle its just all ok :)

Comment: I have added my html and css code above.

Comment: apaul34208, if you read question carefully, you will understand that is totally different question.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that...

Comment: I stumbled on this one after rolling back the edit on the other one. Why did you remove so much info from your other question?

Comment: Load your js and css first and then put your css after it. I copied your code and it looks centered on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

probably are overwriting the top and position property in product. Try this in your CSS::

```css
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon{
position: absolute !important;
top: 50% !important;
}
```

Comment: it is still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this exactly... and let me know.

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon{
position: absolute !Important;
top: 50% !Important;
}
```

Comment: can you share a direct link to that particular page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd like to move the header icon (arrow) to the right to appear to be centered in that section of the tab. If that's what you want to do, the following CSS edit in your Html file might help. It isn't perfect but does give the appearance visually that the arrow 'belongs' with the tab text.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
        left: 20%;
    }
</style>
```